# How to setup Robot Framework standalone jar with SwingLibrary?

Tags: swing, jar, robotframework, gui-testing

I'm using Robot Framework with SwingLibrary to test a Java Swing based application. Since I'm not used to Python and also don't want to setup the Python environment, I decided to go with the Robot standalone JAR version (current version 2.8.4).

My problem is the setup in combination with SwingLibrary (version 1.8.0). I don't know where to put the library such that it gets recognized by Robot.

So far, I have the following test case (mytest.txt):

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SwingLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
MyTestCase
     Start Application     MyApp
```

I tried with putting the standalone jar in conjunction with the test case in a folder, and created one subfolder (called it Lib) where I put the SwingLibrary JAR (and later also extracted the JAR).
I added the SwingLibrary as well as my own application to the classpath, tried executing robot the following way:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/a:Lib/swinglibrary-1.8.0.jar:Lib/MyApp.jar -jar  robotframework-2.8.4.jar  mytest.txt
```

and also with

```
java -jar robotframework-2.8.4.jar mytest.txt
```

I always get one of the following errors:

```
[ WARN ] Imported library 'SwingLibrary' contains no keywords
==============================================================================
Mytest
==============================================================================
MyTestCase                                                           | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'Start Application' found.
```

or

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'mytest.txt': Importing test library 'SwingLibrary' failed: ImportError: No module named SwingLibrary
```

Comment: by now, I've finally got it working with separately installing Jython and installing Robot Framework from Source (i.e. not using the standalone JAR version).

though, it would be interesting if anyone has found a solution for using the standalone version, since in the documentation it is explicitly stated that 

`java -Xbootclasspath/a:Lib/swinglibrary-1.8.0.jar:Lib/MyApp.jar -jar  robotframework-2.8.4.jar  mytest.txt` 

should work.

Comment: Which javac/VM are you using? bootclasspath is non-standard and implemented differently in different javas.  It's usually easier to just skip using -jar in these cases.  See my answer below for that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standalone jar without the -jar option, allowing you to specify the classpath in the standard manner.  The main class for the standalone jar is org.robotframework.RobotFramework, so the syntax would be

```
java -cp robotframework-2.8.4.jar:Lib/swinglibrary-1.8.0.jar:Lib/MyApp.jar org.robotframework.RobotFramework
```

Slightly more verbose but it's standard and so avoids any oddnesses caused by using the non-standard -Xbootclasspath option.

Comment: this definitely works fine!
however, my problem was much simpler: since i'm using a non-english OS version, the classpath has to be separated by ";" instead of ":". I didn't think of that when I copied the line from the Robot documentation. So my classpath was just looking in the wrong place for the libraries...which is why they weren't found.